# Linker errors when building ActiveX DLL in Visual C++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I am trying to create an ActiveX DLL with QT in Visual C++ and I get the following errors when building:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DllCanUnloadNow
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DllGetClassObject
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DllRegisterServer
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DllUnregisterServer
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DumpIDL   
Error   6   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

Am I missing any library includes?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** Here is the header:

```
#ifndef #ifndef TESTACTIVEX_H
#define #ifndef TESTACTIVEX_H

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <ActiveQt/QAxBindable>

#include "ui_testactivex.h"

class TestActiveX : public QWidget, public QAxBindable
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestActiveX(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::TestActiveXClass ui;
};

#endif // #ifndef TESTACTIVEX_H
```

Comment: My guess is your define that is supposed to evaluate to `__declspec(dllexport)`  when building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll is missing a preprocessor define to indicate you are building the dll.

Comment: @drescherjm OK, I set the properties in the Visual Studio 2013 solution to build a DLL, what else do I need to do? What preprocessor define should I set?

Comment: I would have to see your header for the dll. I can't guess what you named your defines..

Comment: I'm using the Qt template (part of the Qt Visual Studio 2013 addin) so here is the header **Placed header in OP as it didn't fit in comment**

Comment: @user3434662 - `Visual Studio 2013 solution to build a DLL`  That isn't enough.  You have to set the project to build an `ActiveX DLL`, not just an ordinary DLL.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not sure if this qualifies as an answer but I have been able to solve this by using Qt Creator to build the code instead of Visual Studio.

I wish I could solve this using Visual Studio but I can. Thanks to all for the help.